# insserv: warning: script 'mathkernel' missing LSB tags and overrides

Tags: ssh, raspbian-wheezy, vnc

I'm trying to run: `sudo update-rc.d avahi-daemon defaults`

But i get the error: `insserv: warning: script 'mathkernel' missing LSB tags and overrides`

I've read that it has something to do with the wolfram engine.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If look at the `/etc/init.d/skeleton` script, in the beginning of it there are two marks : `### BEGIN INIT INFO` and `### END INIT INFO`.

All the data inside those marks is the configuration for runtime dependences and you can look them up in the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

Your script is missing these tags and configuration so `insserv` just uses some defaults.

This is just a warning and is not something to worry about, but you can fix it very easily and then you can be `Linux Standards Base`-compliant (That's what LSB means).

The easiest way to fix the warning, is to copy the LSB tags from the `skeleton` script to the beginning of your `mathkernel` script and just change `skeleton` to `mathkernel`.

Comment: This is not limited to RaspberryPI, for example I started seeing this error when upgrading to Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning, your script will still work. But if you want to remove the warning too just try this command

sudo apt-get remove insserv